# Can I use a remote (inline) blower with a range hood that has its own blower, if I remove the built-in blower?

Tags: kitchens, exhaust-fan, range

I would like to install a remote blower ([inline probably](http://www.broan.ca/products/product/715168f0-30a0-4f9a-aaca-2422e8d0f004#)) and a new range hood, mostly for noise levels.

The thing is, I see two categories of hood:

-'Consumer' grade ones with internal blowers that are typically CA$300-$800 in price, eg. [this one](http://www.broan.ca/products/product/f9bc3ef5-2416-483f-a917-2bc4327a0a63)

-And 'Pro' level hoods with no blower and that area typically >$1000 eg. [this one](http://www.broan.ca/products/product/852837a8-77a9-4b00-9598-9bf0539703d6)

So far as I can tell differences are; 'consumer' grade tend to be less deep than 'pro' and the filters in the 'pro' level tend to be better (eg dishwasher safe).

Is there any reason (eg performance) why I shouldn't get the 'consumer' grade hood, and pull out the blower and then use it with the inline blower?

*I do dislike the consumer and pro monikers since I doubt many professional cooks are working on 30" stoves but that's by the by.

Comment: You might need something to take the place of the internal blower when you remove it to help efficiently direct the air flow.  Are you ok with needing to cut some basic sheet metal parts to do that?  That's all I can think of, but I've never done this.

Comment: @JPhi1618 good point, I can do that.

Comment: The blowers in most hoods are just axial fans in, or just above a circular hole on the baffle above the filter housing that forms a box that the exhaust attaches to behind or above, there's very little in the way of nice airflow management. Probably why many of them are fairly noisy.